# Moment js fromNow guess user timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So what i'm trying to do is basically pass the user's timezone to fromNow function. however it returns this error in the console **TypeError: moment(...).tz(...) is undefined**

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var then = $('#then');
    var usertimezone = moment.tz.guess();
    var date = moment(new Date(then.attr('data-date')));
    moment(date).tz(usertimezone).fromNow();
  });
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth fixed

Comment: Did you use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) or [moment](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: @GilZ i'm using both

Comment: i should point out that moment.fromNow works without guess..

Comment: Did you import required data fro moment-timezone (e.g. [`moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js))? Do you have any other message in console? Can you show how did you import moment and moment-timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by doing the following:

```js
var usertimezone = moment.tz.guess();
var value = moment.utc(new Date(value));
var formatDate = moment.tz(value,usertimezone);
var momentDate = formatDate.fromNow();
```

I believe I had to do `moment.tz` and then `fromNow();`

Comment: Please note that [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) and [`.tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) are **not** the same thing. The first parses the input in the given timezone, while the latter converts a moment object to a given timezone.